# The sign of the tail of Fourier transform of a positive function/ characteristic function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I am interested in  a specific density (positive function) and would like to prove that the tail of its characteristic function (Fourier transform) is positive ($>0$). Here is the density $f(x)=c_\alpha \exp(-|x|^{\alpha})(|x|^\alpha\log(|x|)+1)$, $\alpha \in(1,2)$, $x\in R$, $c_\alpha>0$ is a normalizing constant. I can show that the tail of the characteristic function  is $O(\log(\omega)/\omega^{\alpha+1})$. I just cannot find any theorems for the sign of the limit.  From the numerical analysis I see it is positive.

Comment: $x\in R$ or $x>0$? Or did you want $|x|$ in place of $x$, to make sure the characteristic function is real?

Comment: Looks like regular variation and Karamata's theory is what you are looking for. I would start by looking up the desired result in [K. Soni, R. P. Soni, *Slowly varying functions and asymptotic behavior of a class of integral transforms: I, II, III*. J. Anal. Appl. 49 (1975), 166–179, 477–495, 612–628].

Comment: @IosifPinelis, yes, thank you, edited

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, yes, thank you, that is how I got the rates in limit, however I need to show it is positive. The Fourier transform itself is posttive for some values of $\omega$ and negative for others

Comment: I do not remember well (and I have no time to check it now), but I thought Soni–Soni give explicit constants? I mean, an explicit expression for the limit of $x \hat{f}(x) / f(1/x)$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki  In Soni/Soni and bunch of others the framework is 
$F(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}k(xt)f(t) dt$ and behavior of $f(t)$ at $\infty$ relates to $F(x)$ at $0$.
In my case $F(x)$ is density and $f(t)$ is a characteristic function.    
Basically I have to invert Fourier, which is fine. I have a problem with the assumption about $f(t)$. $f(t)$ is bounded and decreases to zero as $t \to \infty$.  I know $f(t)$ is bounded as positive definite function and it  decreases in absolute value to 0 when $t$ is large, so I cannot quite use these results

Comment: I see. Then, how about the following approach: Write $G(z) = c_1 \log(1 + z^2) / (1 + z^2)^{(\alpha + 1)/2}$. Notice that $g(x)$, the inverse Fourier transform of $G(z)$, is $c_2 + c_3 |x|^\alpha \log (1/|x|) (1 + o(1))$ as $x \to 0$ (see Soni–Soni), and smooth otherwise. Therefore, $f(x) - c_4 g(x)$ is $c_5 + c_6 |x|^\alpha (1 + o(1))$ as $|x| \to 0$ and smoth otherwise, and consequently $F(z) - c_4 G(z)$ is $O(|z|^{-\alpha-1})$ as $|z| \to \infty$. (This is of course just a sketch, and I do not claim it will work. I rather write this to ask whether you tried the above approach).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki well the rate itself is not a problem, the sign of the coefficients is, I need something like $\sim$ not $O(\cdot)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an extended version of my comment *(and now heavily edited)*. Your function $f$ is
$$
 f(x) = c_\alpha e^{-|x|^\alpha} (1 + |x|^\alpha \log |x|) = c_\alpha (1 + |x|^\alpha \log |x| - |x|^\alpha) + O(x^2)
$$
as $x \to 0$. Similarly,
$$
 f'(x) \operatorname{sign} x = c_\alpha (\alpha |x|^{\alpha - 1} \log |x| - (\alpha - 1) |x|^{\alpha - 1}) + O(|x|) ,
$$
and
$$
 f''(x) = c_\alpha (\alpha (\alpha - 1) |x|^{\alpha - 2} \log |x| - (\alpha (\alpha - 1) - (2 \alpha + 1)) |x|^{\alpha - 1}) + O(1) .
$$
Define
$$
 G(z) = \frac{1}{(1 + z^2)^{(\alpha + 1)/2}}
$$
and
$$
 H(z) = \frac{\log(1 + |z|^2)}{(1 + |z|^2)^{(\alpha + 1)/2}} = -\frac{d}{d\alpha} \frac{2}{(1 + |z|^2)^{(\alpha + 1)/2}} \, .
$$
Then the inverse Fourier transforms of $G(z)$ and $H(z)$ are
$$
 g(x) = \frac{1}{2^{\alpha/2} \sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma(\tfrac{\alpha + 1}{2})} \, |x|^{\alpha/2} K_{\alpha/2}(|x|)
$$
and (by the dominated convergence theorem)
$$
 h(x) = -\frac{d}{d\alpha} \biggl( \frac{1}{2^{\alpha/2} \sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma(\tfrac{\alpha + 1}{2})} \, |x|^{\alpha/2} K_{\alpha/2}(|x|) \biggr) .
$$
Note that
$$
 g(x) = \frac{A_\alpha}{2} - \frac{B_\alpha}{2} \, |x|^\alpha + O(x^2) ,
$$
where
$$
 A_\alpha = \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma(\tfrac{1 + \alpha}{2})} , \qquad B_\alpha = \frac{-2^{-\alpha} \Gamma(-\tfrac{\alpha}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma(\tfrac{1 + \alpha}{2})} .
$$
Similarly,
$$
 g'(x) = -\frac{B_\alpha}{2} \, \alpha |x|^{\alpha - 1} + O(|x|) ,
$$
and
$$
 g''(x) = -\frac{B_\alpha}{2} \, \alpha (\alpha - 1) |x|^{\alpha - 2} + O(1) .
$$

The derivative of the Bessel function $K_\nu$ with respect to the parameter $\nu$ can in fact be expressed in terms of other special functions, but the formula is quite complicated and I will not copy it here and only refer to the paper *Higher derivatives of the Bessel functions with respect to the order* by Yu.A. Brychkov, [DOI:10.1080/10652469.2016.1164156](https://doi.org/10.1080/10652469.2016.1164156). An integral expression for this derivative follows directly from the integral expression for $K_\nu(x)$; see [formula 10.32.9 in DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E9), for example. What is important here is that the series expansion of $K_\nu$ near $0$ can be differentiated with respect to $\nu$ term-by-term (and either the explicit expression or the integral formula, both mentioned above, provide a way to make this claim rigorous; I did not verify this carefully, though). It follows that
$$
 h(x) = -A_\alpha' + B_\alpha |x|^\alpha \log |x| - B_\alpha' |x|^\alpha + O(x^2 \log |x|) ,
$$
where primes stand for derivatives with respect to $\alpha$. Similarly,
$$
 h'(x) \operatorname{sign} x = \alpha B_\alpha |x|^{\alpha - 1} \log |x| - (\alpha B_\alpha' - B_\alpha) |x|^{\alpha - 1} + O(|x| \log |x|) ,
$$
and
$$
 h''(x) = \alpha (\alpha - 1) B_\alpha |x|^{\alpha - 2} \log |x| - (\alpha (\alpha - 1) B_\alpha' - (2 \alpha - 1) B_\alpha) |x|^{\alpha - 1} + O(\log |x|) .
$$

Consider an auxiliary function
$$
 \phi(x) = f(x) - \frac{c_\alpha}{B_\alpha} h(x) - \frac{2 c_\alpha (B_\alpha - B_\alpha')}{B_\alpha^2} g(x) .
$$
The constants are chosen in such a way that
$$\begin{gathered}
 \phi(x) = C_\alpha + O(x^2 \log |x|) , \\
 \phi'(x) = O(|x| \log |x|) , \\
 \phi''(x) = O(\log |x|) .
\end{gathered}$$
In order to estimate the Fourier transform of $\phi$, decompose $\phi$ into $\phi_1(x) = \phi(x) u(x)$ and $\phi_2(x) = \phi(x) (1 - u(x))$, where $u$ is smooth, $u = 1$ in $[-1, 1]$ and $u = 0$ outside $(-2, 2)$. Since $\phi_2$ is infinitely smooth and all derivatives of $\phi_2$ are integrable, the Fourier transform of $\phi_2$ decays faster than $|z|^{-p}$ for every $p > 0$, so we only need to handle $\phi_1$.

Observe that for an arbitrary $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$, we have $|\phi_1''(x)| \leqslant a_\alpha \log (e + \tfrac{1}{|x|}) \leqslant b_{\alpha, \varepsilon} (1 + |x|^{-\varepsilon})$ for some constants $a_\alpha$ and $b_{\alpha, \varepsilon}$. Thus, $\phi_1'$ is Hölder continuous with exponent $\beta = 1 - \varepsilon$. As a consequence, the Fourier transform of $\phi_1'$ is $O(|z|^{-\beta})$ as $|z| \to \infty$. It follows that the Fourier transform of $\phi_1$ is $O(|z|^{-1 - \beta})$ for any $\beta \in (0, 1)$, and by choosing $\beta > \alpha - 1$ we find that, in particular, it is $o(|z|^{-\alpha})$. This implies that the Fourier transform of $\phi$ is $o(|z|^{-\alpha})$, and thus, finally
$$
 F(z) = \frac{c_\alpha}{B_\alpha} H(z) + \frac{2 c_\alpha (B_\alpha - B_\alpha')}{B_\alpha^2} G(z) + o(|z|^{-\alpha}) .
$$
This, of course, implies that $F(z) > 0$ when $|z|$ is large enough, as desired.

---

Note: Apparently it can be proved that the Fourier transform of $\phi$ is $O(|z|^{-3} \log |z|)$ as $|z| \to \infty$, and consequently the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ satisfies
$$
 F(z) = \frac{c_\alpha}{B_\alpha} H(z) + \frac{2 c_\alpha (B_\alpha - B_\alpha')}{B_\alpha^2} G(z) + O(|z|^{-3} \log |z|)
$$
as $|z| \to \infty$. The proof of the above bound, however, more effort: it involves monotonicity of $\phi''(x)$ for $x > 0$ small enough, not just Hölder continuity of $\phi'(x)$. The idea is the same as in the proof of $F(z) = O(|z|^{-1-\alpha} \log|z|)$ result mentioned in your post, I suppose. It is not really needed in this answer, and I am short of time, so I will skip the details if you do not mind.

Comment: I do not see why "It follows that the Fourier transform of  is (||−3log||) as ||→∞"  you need an assumption on $F(z)$ , it has to be decreasing  according to the Soni/Soni for Tauberian theorems, am i missing soemthing?

Comment: By the way, $f(x)\sim c_\alpha(1+x^{\alpha}\log(x))$. the sign is $+$

Comment: @TanyaVladi: Thanks for spotting the typo. Regarding your first comment, I edited the answer, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: I guess I still have that same concern, in order for the rates to work out, the assumptions on the functions need tp be checked. Tauberian theorems do not work for ANY functions.  I know how to apply the theorem. I am not sure the assumptions on functions are met. The  monotonicity for $\phi()$,  for example is not there

Comment: @TanyaVladi: I'm afraid I do not understand your concerns: no Tauberian theorem is involved here.

Comment: " Tauberian theorems give the asymptotic behaviour of the original function based on properties of the transform but usually require some restrictions on the original function " ..in my notation as fas as I se it  "original function " is a characteristic function as I care about tis asymptotic behaviour at $\infty$

Comment: big O notation does not give ma a sign as it refers to an absolute value. $\sim$ is a better  choice. The characteristic function I am interested in not monotone, I need to show that it becomes positive and converges to $0$ from above, aka decreases, I am sorry if I was not clear. I can get a rate from differencing Fourier of $\exp(-|x|^{\alpha})$

Comment: @TanyaVladi: Doesn't the last display in the answer show that $F(z) \sim (c_\alpha/B_\alpha) H(z)$ as $|z| \to \infty$?

Comment: I will write a separate comment about it. It seems the framework Soni/Soni is confusing and the devil in the details. What they have is $F(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}k(xt)f(t) dt$, where $F(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ with some rate which is related to the rate of $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. Let $\psi(\cdot)$ be a density, symmetric around $0$. So it seems $F(x)=1-\psi(x)/\psi(0)$, $k(tx)=1-\cos(xt)$ and $f(t)=\phi(t)/\psi(0)$

Comment: Basically, under which assumptions the following is true? If $F(x)\sim G(x)$ as $x\to 0$ means  their transforms  $f(t)\sim g(t)$ as $ t\to\infty$

Comment: @TanyaVladi: This answer (as well as my last comment to the question) does not refer to any Tauberian theorem. In particular, it does not rely on the results of Soni–Soni.

Comment: well then why bother with Bessel functions? $\exp(-|x|^{\alpha})\sim 1-|x|^{\alpha}$, as $x\to 0$ and Fourier of $\exp(-|x|^{\alpha})$ $\sim {\Gamma\{(\alpha+1)/2\}\Gamma(1/\alpha)\over 2  t^{\alpha+1}}$, taking the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ with give the coefficient. I was not sure whether it is a legitimate operation. May be it is - I just cannot find any referees  to  support it

Comment: @TanyaVladi: Sorry, only now I noticed your last comment. Why bother with Bessel functions? Because everything can be made rigorous here. Since the question was bumped anyway, I edited the answer to provide further details. Does this work for you now?

Comment: thank you for getting back to me ."Thus, $\phi_1'$ is compactly supported and Hölder continuous with exponent $\beta$ for any $\beta < 1$. As a consequence, the Fourier transform of $\phi_1'$ is $O(|z|^{-\beta})$ as $|z| \to \infty$. It follows that the Fourier transform of $\phi_1$ is $O(|z|^{-1 - \beta})$ for any $\beta < 1$, and hence, in particular, it is $o(|z|^{-\alpha})$."  I do not understand that part.  Specifically,  why the rate is $o(|z|^{-\alpha})$.  This is the critical park of the proof and I was struggling with it when you posted your original proof. Thank you

Comment: @TanyaVladi: If we choose any $\beta \in (\alpha-1, 1)$, then $O(|z|^{-1-\beta})$ is $o(|z|^{-\alpha})$ (both as $|z| \to \infty$), right?

Comment: OK, I guess I do not understand, how you can choose  $\beta $ and  why $\phi_1^{\prime}$ is Hölder continuous with exponent $\beta $for any $\beta<1$"

Comment: sorry the whole trick with $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ is new to me, why  did you ignore $f^{\prime}$ in your argument about $\phi_1^{\prime}$

Comment: @TanyaVladi: I am sorry, I do not quite understand your last two comments. I added again some details to my answer, but I am not sure if they address your concerns. Note, however, that I am no expert in asymptotic analysis, there are certainly better ways to write this argument.

Comment: Thank you for your details. It is more clear now. I have seen that trick  with multiplying by $u$ before, here, on this site, I have not seen it in the textbooks or papers though. I really appreciate your attention to my problem.